# Fatal Python error: none_dealloc: deallocating None: bug likely caused by a refcount error in a C extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, python-3.11

I'm running a script with this version of python:

> Python 3.11.3 (main, May  2 2023, 23:12:30) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux

The script uses these imports:

```
import datetime
import time
import mysql.connector
import traceback
import tracemalloc
import logging
import sys
```

After a while it crashes with this output:

```
Fatal Python error: none_dealloc: deallocating None: bug likely caused by a refcount error in a C extension
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007fa201272280 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/main.py", line 119 in <module>

Extension modules: _mysql_connector (total: 1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could the problem be? It worked find with python3.9 but I had to upgrade python (by compiling it from source) and now I have this error on every .py I run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for the solution of the same problem.
After some minutes running my script it gets deallocating None.
When running on pycharm the problem occurs faster then in linux terminal.

Looking to your code i realize that the only similarity is the mysql connector library. maybe the problem is there. i'll do a downgrade and see if the problem persists. I recommend you to do the same.

Comment: I did a downgrade of mysql connector and it works well. 
Try the pip install mysql-connector-python == 8.0.20 it works to me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. definitely mysql.connector. what I did is I used pool_reset_session=True in every 10th batch, now it works fine. can't use it all the time, then it slows down and stops, but on every 10th no noticeable performance change and no more crashes.

Comment: solved by upgrading to python3.12